# Limit foreac-object

Tags: powershell, for-loop, foreach-object

I'm looping through an array but I only want the first 10 results that meets my conditions. But I have no idea where to start. I'm thinking I need a for-loop like `for ($i=0;$i -le 10;$i++)` and do $i-- when the IF statement is true. I'm a total rookie :D

```
$result | ForEach-Object {
    if (($_.City -contains 'Oklahoma') -or ($_.City -like 'Chicago')){
    }else {
    $dosomething
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out one way to do it. Is there any other/better way to do it?

```
$i=0;
$result | ForEach-Object {
     if (($_.City -contains 'Oklahoma') -or ($_.City -like 'Chicago') -or (($i -ge 10)){}
     else {
           $dosomething
           $i++;
     }
}
```

Comment: Please be aware that `-contains` doesn't work (like you might expect) on strings. You probably want `$_.City -like "*Oklahoma*"` instead

Answer (score 0):

The usual way is to keep a counter for results. When desired number of results are found, a `break` statement will terminate the loop. Like so,

```
$hits = 0
$maxresults = 10
$result | ForEach-Object {
  if ($_ -match "whatever" ){
   ++$hits
   do-stuff
  } else {
    do-something-else
  }
  if($hits -ge $maxresults) { break }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a one-liner then this might help:

`$top10 = $result | Where-Object {($_.City -contains 'Oklahoma') -or ($_.City -like 'Chicago')} | Select-Object -First 10 -Skip 0`